# Getting a correct regex for word starting and ending with different letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, regex-negation

I am quite new to regex and I right now Have a problem formulating a regex to match a string where the first and last letter are different. I looked up on the internet and found a regex that just does it's opposite. i.e. matches words that have same starting and ending letter. Can anyone please help me to understand if I can negeate this regex in some way or can create a new regex to match my requirements. The regex that needs to be modiifed or changed is:

```py
^\s|^[a-z]$|^([a-z]).*\1$
```

This matches these Strings :

```
aba,
a,
b,
c,
d,
" ", 
cccbbbbbbac,
aaaaba
```

But I want it to match strings like:

```
aaabbcz,
zba,
ccb,
cbbbba
```

Can anyone please help me in this regard? Thank you.

**Note: I will be using this with Python Regex, so the regex should be compataible to be used with Python.**

Comment: What about `a`? should that pass or fail?

Comment: fail because a is a single letter so it is starting with a and ending with a only

Comment: The negative lookahead allows to ensure that a particular pattern does not follow: `^([a-z]).*(?!\1).$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a regex for this, just use

```py
s[0] != s[-1]
```

where `s` is your string. If you *must* use a regex, you can use this:

```
^(.).*(?!\1).$
```

This looks for

- `^` : beginning of string
- `(.)` : a character (captured in group 1)
- `.*` : some number of characters
- `(?!\1).` : a character which is *not* the character captured in group 1
- `$` : end of string

Regex [demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KJynvV/1)

Comment: @SaikatSahana: Since this answer worked for you, you should mark this answer as accepted!!

Answer (score 1):

This part of your pattern `^([a-z]).*\1$` only accounts for chars a-z, but you also want to exclude `" "`

You can rewrite that pattern by putting the part after the capture group inside a negative lookahead.

```
^(.)(?!.*\1$).+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(.)` Capture a single char (including spaces) in group 1
- `(?!.*\1$)` Negative lookahead, assert that the string does not end with the same character
- `.+` Match 1+ characters so that the string has a minimum of 2 characters

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TaM7jJ/1).

If the string should start and end with a non whitespace character to prevent / trailing trailing spaces, you can start the match with a non whitespace character `\S` and also end the match with a non whitespace character.

```
^(\S)(?!.*\1$).*\S$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w8fTK8/1).